# ModemManager failing to support any device (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, usb-modem, modem-manager

I am using a Huawei E3531 with a new SIM card and empty Micro SD.
I have also attempted a Nokia Symbian Phone, and some generic Qualcom device.

After some forum digging I managed to get my Huawei to connect me to the internet fine, however what I actually wanted to use it for was receiving SMS.

I am attempting to use ModemManager and ModemManager Gui to do this.

Only once did ModemManager Gui display my Huawei which was after running

```
modeprobe option
```

It only showed it for a few minutes and shortly after disappeared again, the command no longer produces the same result.

The modem only started connecting to the internet after doing:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-axe027.rules
```

And inputting:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/99-axe027.rules
# contains axe027 udev rule to patch default
# FTDI product id to AXE027 product id (0xbd90)
SYSFS{idProduct}=="12d1",
SYSFS{idVendor}=="1f01",
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -q ftdi_sio product=0x12d1 vendor=0x1f01"
```

Which was generously provided by [this forum post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525016/cant-open-port-dev-ttyusb0)

`usb-devices` result for the correct device produces:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=07 Cnt=06 Dev#= 14 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=14dc Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

**Now the important part**: the result of `sudo systemctl status ModemManager`

```
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-09-14 19:16:08 BST; 40min ago
 Main PID: 9697 (ModemManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           └─9697 /usr/sbin/ModemManager

Sep 14 19:16:08 <user>-Gnome systemd[1]: Starting Modem Manager...
Sep 14 19:16:08 <user>-Gnome ModemManager[9697]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.4.12) starting in system bus...
Sep 14 19:16:08 <user>-Gnome systemd[1]: Started Modem Manager.
Sep 14 19:16:10 <user>-Gnome ModemManager[9697]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8': not supported by any plugin
Sep 14 19:16:10 <user>-Gnome ModemManager[9697]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/0000:03:00.0': not supported by any plugin
```

I've been looking for a solution for a couple days now and no luck :(

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

I may attempt to draw an image based on the  username of the most helpful answer (depending on whether or not my graphics tablet works in Ubuntu...)

Comment: *update* Nokia phone modem works now, I needed to put it into Nokia Suite mode (I didn't properly read the notes section on the ModemManager site.) so unrelated to Huwei issue, any advice is still gladly accepted and my Graphics Tablet works now so I'm raising the bounty:  *in addition to drawing a picture of your username I will take a single request.*